# "Or" in If Blocks in Ruby

Tags: ruby

So I am writing a Ruby program for school that changes the value of a boolean to true if a certain value is either 1 or 3, and to false if it is 0 or 2.  Since I come from a Java background, I thought that this code should work: `if n == 1 || n == 3`

But it does not.  So my question here is is it possible to use an "Or" expression thingy in If blocks in Ruby?  I know that my current situation could be solved easily by just something like the following:

```
if n == 0
    t_o_f = false
elsif n == 1
    t_o_f = true
```

Et Cetera.  But I want to know if I can use an Or in If blocks for the future.

Comment: Is something missing from the `elsif`?

Comment: What happens when you try `if n == 1 || n == 3`?

Comment: How is it not working? Seems to work for me: https://gist.github.com/3912671

Comment: The condition you say does not work should actually work.  Can you show a simple example where it is not doing what you expect?

Comment: `if n == 4 || n == 5 puts "Yes"­` when `n = 5`, (in irb) says "This code is not valid Ruby"

Comment: OOPS.  I have my inline if statement backwards....... `facepalm`

Comment: Why do you need to mention that it returns false for 0 or 2? What happens for inputs other than 0, 1, 2, 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, any expression can be used in an `if` condition, including those using the `||` (logical or) operator.

As with Java, Ruby's `||` operator short-circuits.  That is, if the left side is true, the right side is not evaluated.

Idiomatic ruby uses *postfix if* for one-liners:

```
puts "Yes" if n == 4 || n == 5
```

Avoid *postfix if* the line is long, however, and break it into multiple lines:

```
if n == 4 || n == 5
  puts "This is a big long string to be output....................."
end
```

That's because *postfix if* can get visually lost at the end of a long line.

You *can* have a one-liner with *prefix if*, but it's not commonly seen:

```
if n == 4 || n == 5 then puts "foo" end
```

or, perhaps:

```
if n == 4 || n == 5 ; puts "foo" ; end
```

This is really a multi-line if condensed into one line; the semicolons act as line breaks.

When testing for multiple conditions, it can sometimes be valuable to use `Array#include?`:

```
puts "foo" if [4, 5].include?(n)
```

The value of this for only two conditions is not that great.  For three or more, it reads well.

Comment: You don't need the second semicolon, and you can use the `then` keyword instead of the first one.

Comment: @Jörg, Thanks.  I never use prefix-if one-liners and had forgotten that form.

Answer (score 1):

The or operator works, and you can write the keyword too:

```
if n==1 or n==2
end
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_operators.htm

And you could also write what you want this way:

```
x = (n%2) ? true : false
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Wayne Conrad: if there is little or no 'logic' deciding if n is true or false, then this is also a good option:

```
result = case n
  when 1, 3 then true
  when 0, 2 then false
end
```